# Display HTML special chars from Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I used to have PHP code that will use `htmlspecialchars` before inserting data ("â€¢         ") to MySQL then when I display in HTML I just do `echo` out from PHP and it displays fine.

But once I switched to use backbone/jQuery as the client code to do API to get data then it render the HTML page then it doesn't display the bullet properly.

I just wonder if there some simple way without adding any js plugin (as I don't want to add more download to a request) to display it properly?

Comment: Can you please give an example with the differtences?

Comment: The three characters quoted have the encoding `E2 80 A2` in some Windows encodings such as cp1252. It is _also_ the UTF-8 encoding of the unicode character `U+2022 "BULLET"`.